# What pattern of event driven procession does asyncio implement?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

`asyncio` is an event driven core lib of python 3.4. I know twisted, a similar lib for `asyncio`, implements the `Reactor` pattern, but what kind of pattern does `asyncio` implement?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it uses reactor for posix. Windows implementation has proactor event loop too.

Comment: Are `windows_events.py` and `unix_events.py` good starting points for investigation?

Comment: No. `unix_events.py` is about signal handling and subprocess execution. `windows_events.py` is overcomplicated due Windows io completion port nature.

As the best starting point I recommend `selector_events.py`.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov you're referring to this [selector_events.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py)? Would you point out the [proactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern) and [reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) patterns in the code that you referred to?

Comment: Reactor pattern is used for every loop implementation  except `asyncio.windows_event:ProactorEventLoop` obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As @AndrewSvetlov answered,  Python already will select the most performant selector for you, depending on your operating system. Different selector event loops will be, ensuring to get the tightest loop, the most performant selector available on your operating system. So it implements both patterns.